# Particle system only shows one particle?

Tags: particles

I'll create a new cube, give it a particle system with a count of 1000, then set it to fill the volume. This should create a random plethora of 1000 particles inside the cube, right?
[image]
I'm not sure why this is happening. It always happens, not just this scene. Same thing happens when using face or vertex.

Settings:
[image]

Comment: Try going to the cache, and clicking 'free all bakes'  if that doesn't work, try creating a new blend in a new (different) folder. Blender can get weird when there is baked caches in the same directory.

Comment: your images dont show up here

Comment: It will eventually add all of them, but you have it set to add them from frame 1 to frame 200. I think you would get the effect that you want if you set the end to frame 1.

Comment: @pycoder Your solution worked, the particles weren't showing up on the first frame. Is there any way to make all the particles be birthed and not move or disappear or anything throughout the whole animation?

Comment: @JoshSilveous Turn off physics by setting it to `No`, do what I said (set the start and end to the same value), and then give them a really long lifetime...you have it set to the default of 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

It will eventually add all of them, but you have it set to add them from frame 1 to frame 200. I think you would get the effect that you want if you set the end to frame 1.

Turn off physics by setting it to `No`, set the start and end to the same value, and then give them a really long lifetime...you have it set to the default of 50.

[image]

[image]